# API Add-on SDK - recently closed tabs and windows

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a special API for Firefox add-ons that returned recently closed tabs and windows or the only solution is collect their manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't one, but both the [windows module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/windows.html#close) and the [tabs module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#close_4) have a `close` event, so it's very easy to collect them manually:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var closedTabs = [];
tabs.on("close", function(tab) {
    closedTabs.unshift(tab);
});
var mostRecentlyClosedTab = closedTabs[0];
```